# Vertically center UITableViewCell in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xamarin.ios

How would you go about centering a cell vertically in a UITableViewCell when there's only one or two cells? Apple does this quite often in their apps, for example in the Settings app, when editing the date.

Here's an example: 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd consider putting a large, transparent UITableViewCell above it (ala how you do it in gitHubby with the user's info, but with no data).

thats the benefit of have 480 pixels high. you can put something in, fixed size, and it'll JUST WORK.

Or put a \n\n\n containing section header in, which is also invisible and transparent.

oh for Spy++ or something for running iOS apps :)

Comment: I like the approach with the section header. :-D

Comment: Great idea putting \n as the title of the section, but that doesn't work perfectly. One line is too small, two lines too much. Having a custom sized header works, though.

Comment: well it won't just work now with the iphone 5. any better solutions?

Answer (score 14):

I went with the header strategy, and dynamically calculate the content height to center all content in the table.  The advantage of this is that it will work with any table content or view size:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    CGFloat contentHeight = 0.0;
    for (int section = 0; section < [self numberOfSectionsInTableView: tableView]; section++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < [self tableView: tableView numberOfRowsInSection: section]; row++) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: row inSection: section];
            contentHeight += [self tableView: tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
        }
    }
    return (tableView.bounds.size.height - contentHeight)/2;
}


- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        return view;
}
```

Comment: I am getting contentHeight -1 always

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        var contentHeight:CGFloat = 0.0
        for section in (0 ..< numberOfSections(in: tableView)) {
            for row in (0 ..< self.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)) {
                let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: row, section: section)
                contentHeight += self.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath as IndexPath)
            }
        }

        return (tableView.bounds.size.height - contentHeight)/2;
    }
```