# How to put UITableView always in center of UIView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I would like to implement a `UITableView` in the center of a `UIView`. Initially it has only 2 or 3 rows. When user adds more rows, it would extend in vertical direction, while the whole content remains in the center, as shown as below:

[image]

Is it possible to do that with `UITableView`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be done using **UIScrollView's `contentOffset` property**.

1. Make your tableView's frame sitting in the bounds:

   ```
   tableView.frame = self.view.bounds;
   tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
   ```
2. Declare a method -layoutTableView:

   ```
   - (void)layoutTableView {
       CGSize contentSize = tableView.contentSize;
       CGSize boundsSize = tableView.bounds.size;
       CGFloat yOffset = 0;
       if(contentSize.height < boundsSize.height) {
           yOffset = floorf((boundsSize.height - contentSize.height)/2);
       }
       tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, yOffset);
   }
   ```
3. When you call `[tableView reloadData]`, just call `[self layoutTableView]` afterwards.

Comment: See the following : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759374/changing-the-size-of-uitableview-programmatically

Comment: It's not the answer to the question and it adjusts frame. In my example frame can be equal to `self.view.bounds`.

Comment: thanks kashiv, but initially it might has just 2 rows, when u define its frame as self.view.bounds. the rows might not be shown in the middle?

Comment: OK, you can call `[self layoutTableView]` inside `– tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: I think `tableView.contentInset` works better than `tableView.contentOffset` for this situation. It makes the content return to center after a scroll, where `contentOffset` simply changes where the scroll is. `tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(yOffset, 0.f, yOffset, 0.f);`

Answer (score 8):

Another solution is to adjust the content inset of the table view since the content offset solution didn't work for me. Heres the basic idea (inserted into a custom UITableView subclass):

```
- (void)reloadData {
    [super reloadData];
    [self centerTableViewContentsIfNeeded];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self centerTableViewContentsIfNeeded];
}

- (void)centerTableViewContentsIfNeeded {
    CGFloat totalHeight = CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds);
    CGFloat contentHeight = self.contentSize.height;
    //If we have less content than our table frame then we can center
    BOOL contentCanBeCentered = contentHeight < totalHeight;
    if (contentCanBeCentered) {
        self.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(ceil(totalHeight/2.f - contentHeight/2.f), 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        self.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    }
}
```

For the Swift-hearted here's a Playground:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import XCPlayground

class CenteredTable: UITableView {
    override func reloadData() {
        super.reloadData()
        centerTableContentsIfNeeded()
    }

    override func  layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        centerTableContentsIfNeeded()
    }

    func centerTableContentsIfNeeded() {
        let totalHeight = CGRectGetHeight(bounds)
        let contentHeight = contentSize.height
        let contentCanBeCentered = contentHeight < totalHeight
        if (contentCanBeCentered) {
            contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: ceil(totalHeight/2 - contentHeight/2), left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0);
        } else {
            contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        }
    }
}

class DataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    let items = ["Mr", "Anderson", "Welcome", "Back", "We", "Missed", "You"]
    func registerReusableViewsWithTable(tableView: UITableView) {
        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .Center
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }
}

let dataSource = DataSource()
let table = CenteredTable(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 800), style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
table.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
let container = UIView(frame: table.frame)
container.addSubview(table)
dataSource.registerReusableViewsWithTable(table)
table.dataSource = dataSource
table.reloadData()
XCPShowView("table", container)
container
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't use your headers in the tableview you can dynamically calculate the height of the cells compared to the tableviews bound height.

Kudos to
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15026532/1847601

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    CGFloat contentHeight = 0.0;
    for (int section = 0; section < [self numberOfSectionsInTableView: tableView]; section++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < [self tableView: tableView numberOfRowsInSection: section]; row++) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: row inSection: section];
            contentHeight += [self tableView: tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
        }
    }
    return (tableView.bounds.size.height - contentHeight)/2;
}


- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        return view;
}
```

Comment: If you do not have dynamic height (all the same height cells) and so you are not implementing the "heightForRowAtIndex" then you can replace two lines in the middle for the two For's with "contentHeight += tableView.rowHeight;"

Answer (score 3):

No need to have that bulky logic. Just use the following line in `cellForRowAt()`:

Swift:

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: (tableView.bounds.height/2 - cell.bounds.height/2), left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Objective-C:

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake((tableView.bounds.height/2 - cell.bounds.height/2), 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3

```
private func hightTableView() {
    yourTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: Int((Int(view.frame.height) - rowHeight * yourArrayData.count) / 2), width: widthTable, height: rowHeight * yourArrayData.count)
}
```